# Authentication of phone number is not working on IOS Devices [Firebase]

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

Authentication of phone number is not working. "I am not a robot" is not verifying therefore I am not receiving the code. The sign-in and sign-up are working on Android devices, but they are not working on IOS devices, they are only working on the ios simulator.

I am receiving the following message: `NativeFirebaseError: [auth/internal-error] Unable to load external reCAPTCHA dependencies!`

**Note: I already enabled the phone sign-in method and I already added URL Types.

Comment: any updates about this issue @MarynaAzeez because I am facing this issue

Comment: @MahmoudGamalEl-Din It was the Firebase version that was causing the issue, you have to use the same version of Firebase Libraries. I used the following: "@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.0.0",

Answer (score 0):

It was the Firebase version that was causing the issue, I used the same version of Firebase Libraries. I used the following versions:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.0.0", 
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.0.0", 
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.0.0"
```